# How to prevent tailwind from centering content automatically?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, tailwind-css, vite

I'm currently trying tailwindcss along with Vite and recently something is being super annoying and couldn't find a solution yet.

Looks like tailwind automatically centers the content and I'm struggling on working with flex components due to this.

This is a code piece from what I'm using, it's very simple but you can see that the content is being centered from default and can't change that behavior yet D:

```
export const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      Wow
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is what it looks like

[image]

And if I try to use a combination of flex components it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Any chances there could still be some default styles remain in `App.css` or `index.css` created by Vite?

Comment: @JohnLi it was indeed created by Vite so my bad on that, and thanks for pointing that out. Just forgot to remove the boilerplate code D:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Tailwind-css` doesn't center the element by `default`.

I suspect this is being observed , because the parent of `Home()` component has a flex property which is center, so divs of `Home()` component is taking the center of the screen

Or

Maybe `Vite` in the boilerplate, Check the boilerplate once, as `Vite` boilerplate usually centers the `div` elements

Comment: After some research i figured out, vite by default centers the div. May be that is what is causing the undesired behavior

Answer (score 1):

Tailwind doesn't automatically center content, but it might be from vite's default styling in the 'style.css' file. Be sure to check other